# Warning: cannot find svn location for distribute==0.6.16dev-r0

Tags: python, django, pip

I am getting the following error with that command:

```
$pip freeze > requirements.txt 
Warning: cannot find svn location for distribute==0.6.16dev-r0
```

This is my requirements.txt file beforehand:

```
Django==1.3
django-registration==0.7
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First, I'd note that is not an error, but rather a *warning* (though it is a serious one).

This appears to be an open issue in pip, judging by this [issue page](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/287) on the github repository. The problem arises when pip is installing something a development version that is held on a repository that is not SVN. One example that issue page provides:

```
mkvirtualenv test --no-site-packages
workon test
pip install flask==dev
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

It will print this result to standard error:

```
Warning: cannot find svn location for Flask==0.9-devdev-20120114
```

But the file will still have:

```
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
Flask==0.9-devdev-20120114
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

However, I won't be able to use this file in the future to install Flask. See here:

```
mkvirtualenv test2 --no-site-packages
workon test2
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Will output the error:

```
Downloading/unpacking Flask==0.9-devdev-20120114 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==0.9-devdev-20120114 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No distributions matching the version for Flask==0.9-devdev-20120114 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Storing complete log in /Users/dgrtwo/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Where's the solution?

Answer (score 20):

```
sudo pip install --upgrade distribute
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here please?

Comment: This issue is a bug in the distribute package, so when you upgrade it, you solve the problem.

Comment: also please check (and upvote) MikeTwo's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28596824/342293

Answer (score 3):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but `sudo pip install --upgrade distribute` borked my pip installation. Pip version 1.4.1.  After running that command, pip freeze gives an AssertionError.

The fix for THAT is `sudo pip install setuptools==7.0`

The two solutions combined fixed the svn URL warning.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem trying to create a django project and deploy it on heroku.  I think the problem was related to having multiple copies of django.  Deleting django located at

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django
```

and the reinstalling seemed to solve the problem.  I was able to create the `requirements.txt` without a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Ron's idea borked my pip installation too, and MikeTwo's fix did not fix it.

I ended up removing pip and re-installing is, as found [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1093) (UzLA's comment). Remove package:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-pip
```

Download official pip installer:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

install it:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

`pip freeze` worked properly after this. It did give `SNIMissingWarning` and `InsecurePlatformWarning`, see [the docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning), but that's not the issue here.

**Note**: the source of this fix as  has a 4th step, to set up a symlink from /usr/local/bin/pip to /usr/bin. This may not be necessary. Try `stat /usr/local/bin/pip`. That should report a regular file, size 200 bytes or so. You can `less /usr/local/bin/pip` to see what's in it. Then do `echo $PATH` to check if `/usr/local/bin` is in there. If it is, the symlink is not needed.