# Yet another `bash: pip: command not found`

Tags: python, debian, pip

Lots of installation instructions tell you to do `pip install [package]`. But in my case that won't work, it'll say `-bash: pip: command not found`

`python pip install [package]` works OK. Likewise for `easy_install`, won't run by itself, will run when started with python.

I'm confused as to how it *should* work. Pip is no executable, there's no module called pip.py, there's only `<path>\pip\__init__.py`. So if `pip install [package]` is to work properly, the bash shell must understand when to act as a python interpreter. Which it doesn't.

I don't believe all those install instructions are off. So I must be missing something. What?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780717/bash-pip-command-not-found) didn't help, nor did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30017353/1016065), in fact trying `sudo apt-get install python-pip` led to what I think is an [unresolved bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=787165;msg=5). So I had to revert to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578125/1016065), to get me a somewhat working pip. (Now read again from the top).

**Edit**: Python 2.7. Not 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempts to re-install or fix failed. So I removed pip completely and did what I hope is a clean install. First:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-pip
```

Then delete pips caches and existing downloads, where appropriate (in my case, I left still working `pips` inside virtual environments alone):

```
sudo find / -type d -name 'pip*'
sudo rm -rf <dirname>
```

Then download the official pip installer and install it:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py 
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Now `pip freeze` runs without errors. In addition:

- the cause was that the pip-script was gone. After the re-install, it's there again: `/usr/local/bin/pip`. So what I thought:

  > the bash shell must understand when to act as a python interpreter. Which it doesn't.

  is not right. The shell *will* launch a python script, if its shebang-line  points to the proper interpreter. Learning all the time...
- many sources suggest to `sudo apt-get install python-pip`. That's wrong. `apt-get` is several versions behind the current stable one. Mixing versions leads to all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 4):

Most packages, including Debian's package, adds a `/usr/bin/pip` (or `pip3`, see below). See: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/python-pip/filelist

I *think* the pip installer via get-pip.py also does this.

The file basically relays it through python via console_scripts.

Check your /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin for pip. (if you installed pip outside of a package manager or without root/sudo then they probably don't exist). But they should...

If you're on python3, the file might be named pip3 so check /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin for that instead.

You can add an entry to your .bash_aliases to alias if you want the shortcut:

```
alias pip='pip3'
# or
# alias pip='python pip'
```

Comment: The alias is a nice workaround, thanks. There's a symlink `/usrbin/pip -> /usr/local/bin/pip` but the latter doesn't exist.

Comment: How did you install your current pip? Last place to look would be `$HOME/.local/bin/` but that would only be if you manually told python to install pip locally. If you have a symlink at `/usr/bin/pip` and the target doesn't exist, I think it should error when trying to run the pip command instead of saying command not found. `which pip` will there you where it's looking.

Comment: Which pip says nothing. Empty line.

Comment: Then it's not in your PATH, so you don't have a `/usr/bin/pip`. Was that a typo or is the directory actually named `/usrbin/pip` instead of `/usr/bin/pip` ? Could also check the output of `echo $PATH` to make sure /usr/bin is in it (but it definitely should be).

Comment: That's really strange... Anyway, my best guess is to check your `/root/.local/bin` if it exists or your main user's `$HOME/.local/bin`. The alias should work for you in the meantime, but having a questionable environment is never good for a developer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128976/discussion-between-rolfbly-and-hong).

Answer (score 1):

use `python3 -m pip install X` where X is the package name like if I want to install Pillow Python Imaging Library is will use

```
python3 -m pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me.

Purge and reinstall pip.

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```